# AWS Glue 2.0 Connection Timeout

Tags: python, pyspark, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am trying to use AWS Glue to transfer data from EMR Hive to Redshift.
While creating EMR cluster I mentioned to use Glue Catalog for tables metadata.
Also created and tested Redshift glue connection and crawler.

To test my script I created a dev-endpoint and open jupyter notebook. Below is the code

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.window import *
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType, TimestampType
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
import sys
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
spark = glueContext.sparkSession

customer = spark.table('demo.customers').where(col("insert_timestamp") >= '2020-04-01')
cust_dyn = DynamicFrame.fromDF(customer, glueContext, 'cust_dyn')
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(frame = cust_dyn, database = "classic_models", catalog_connection = 'Redshift',
                                             table_name = "dev_classic_models_customers", 
                                             redshift_tmp_dir = 's3://temp/')
```

Now when I run this by creating a glue 2.0 job with Redshift connection, I get timeout error mentioned below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/Demo", line 16, in <module>
    customer = spark.table('demo.customers').where(col("insert_timestamp") >= '2020-04-01')
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 780, in table
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.table(tableName), self._wrapped)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'java.lang.RuntimeException: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to glue.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:443 [glue.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/3.7.225.56, glue.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/13.234.179.141, glue.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/13.127.192.167, glue.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/13.235.123.170] failed: connect timed out;'
```

One thing I noticed when I don't add Redshift connection and just use select statement then it runs fine.
But without Redshift connection I cannot transfer data to Redshift db.
Any reason why it's failing tr what can be done?
Thanks

Comment: Can you confirm the subnet used for dev endpoint is private and not public ?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy I haven't provided any subnet for the dev-endpoint. Subnet field is empty

Comment: are you in ap-south-1 region ? Which region your redshift_tmp_dir located?